# i need to proove that An∪B→A∪B

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $A_n\rightarrow A$, show that $(A_n \cup B) \rightarrow (A \cup B)$.

My attempted solution used $\lim \inf(A_n \cup B)$ and lim sup but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Define

$$
C_n=(A_n\cup B)-(A\cup B)\\
D_n=(A\cup B)-(A_n\cup B)
$$
and prove that $C_n\to \emptyset$ and $D_n\to \emptyset$.